# Convert SVG to PNG and download, vue 2

Tags: svg, vuejs2, png

I'm looking for a clean way to convert a SVG to PNG and download, in Vue 2. What is the best approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to come up with this solution:

```html
save() {
      const a = document.querySelector("a");
      const triggerDownload = (imgURI: string) => {
        const evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
          view: window,
          bubbles: false,
          cancelable: true,
        });

        a?.setAttribute("download", "FileName.png");
        a?.setAttribute("href", imgURI);
        a?.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

        a?.dispatchEvent(evt);
      };
      const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      data = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(
        document.getElementById("svgId") as Node
      );
      const DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

      const img = new Image();
      const svgBlob = new Blob([data], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" });
      const url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

      img.onload = function () {
        ctx?.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

        const imgURI = canvas
          .toDataURL("image/png")
          .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");

        triggerDownload(imgURI);
        ctx?.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      };

      img.src = url;
    },
```